# Where can I find a TDFN/14 part definition for Eagle?

Tags: eaglecad, packages

I'm new to Eagle (previously only worked with Fritzing) and I'm porting a layout into Eagle that uses the MAX98306 IC (http://www.maximintegrated.com/datasheet/index.mvp/id/7413).

I can't seem to find the right package type for Eagle, but it's possible it can go under another name and I just don't know what I'm really looking for!

**Edit/update**:
I have found reference to the exact IC I want in SparkFuns Eagle library: https://github.com/sparkfun/SparkFun-Eagle-Libraries. Specifically in the file SparkFun-PowerIC.lbr. I have added the library to Eagle and can see a ton more parts than before, but searches don't bring up that specific item.

**Result!**:
OK I finally figured it out. Once a new library is added you may need to 'enable' it's part sets by clicking the dot to the right of the part set in the Control Panel window in Eagle. Man this program has some major UI issues. :)

Comment: Done! Thanks Peter J, will bear that in mind in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK I finally figured it out. Once a new library is added you may need to 'enable' it's part sets by clicking the dot to the right of the part set in the Control Panel window in Eagle. Man this program has some major UI issues. :)